# What is the purpose of the rat shooting level in Theme Hospital?

Tags: theme-hospital

In *Theme Hospital*'s single player, if you shoot enough rats with the cursor during a single level, your 'player piece' on the level select screen will be moved to a rat-shooting minigame with a little fanfare instead of sliding to the next level on the board.

You're placed in an empty hospital with no rooms, no patients and no staff and there are rats all over the place for you to shoot. There doesn't seem to be any objectives on this level, and it just ends arbitrarily.

How does this level work? What's the objective? And what do you get for winning?

(i.e. do you get extra research? bonus staff? bonus money?)

Answer (score 3):

It is just a bonus level for you to practice shooting without any objectives/risks. You can access that level through codes as well if you like it (7287 on the fax machine)