# How can I skip the rat shooting level in Theme Hospital?

Tags: theme-hospital

There is a "bonus" level in Theme Hospital where you get to shoot as many rats as you can in the time it takes for your super inefficient cleaning crew to clear the building. According to the internet, it's triggered as a reward for killing off lots of rats in the regular levels. This [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/333654/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-rat-shooting-level-in-theme-hospital) makes it clear that it has no consequences or rewards, and can be triggered by entering cheat codes on the fax machine.

I personally hate the rat shooting mechanic in this game, so this "bonus" is like a punishment to me. I keep accidentally triggering it because I happen to kill rats in my hospital during the normal course of business.

**Is there a way to skip the rat shooting level?** Or do I just let it run while I get some coffee or something?

Answer (score 1):

Blade Wraith's answer is misleading. There is no way to go back to the "level select" screen (which isn't even a selection screen).

You will need to leave the game running. The rat challenge is designed so that you extend the time you get by killing rats (which the handymen need to clean). As long as you don't engage with it, it doesn't take very long (5-10 minutes at most).

You could also try changing the game speed to And Then Some More, making it go even faster, though some versions may disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since i played, but from memory:

The next level is unlocked at the end of the current one. when the game loads the rat level you can either get yourself a coffee (as you suggested) while it runs down the timer, or exit the level and go back to the level select screen at which point you should be able to select the next full level from the wheel

Comment: How do you exit to go back to the level select screen? The only options I have are 'load', 'save', and 'quit'. Quit takes me back to the original menu, where I have 'continue previous game', 'load', 'new game', and 'start network game' options.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, again its been a while, if continue just takes you back to the rat level, then i think it was in the load option, you had the level select wheel, thats what you're looking for, or just keep the hospitals tidier and there won't be rats...